Pseudo Filesystem vs Virtual Filesystem - What's the difference?
What is the difference between a pseudo filesystem, and a virtual filesystem?
I'm reading a couple of comments that they are the same.
Thanks!!!

I'm not familiar with the term 'pseudo filesystem'.  The closest I can think of would be the APIs into kernel data structures that are presented as filesystems like /proc.  Would you please add to you question an example of where someone is using that term?

@SottoVoce, here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/procfs.5.html

I'll have some bad news: what these words mean, and whether there's a difference between them, depends on the context. (That's true for any word, by the way.)
For example, man procfs calls /proc a "pseudo-filesystem", and the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy calls it a "virtual filesystem", and a "process information pseudo-file system".
So, that's it. You have two authorative sources in the field of filesystems on Linux, using the two terms interchangeably. You can stop here: if anyone means something very specific with them, they will have to tell you what their specific definition of these terms are.
For example, in the context of the Linux VFS layering system, "virtual" does have a specific meaning – but it's not compatible with how The Linux Filesystem Hierarchy uses it for /proc. In other words:
Human language is messy, blurry and needs context. For any word describing a concept that might have evolved relatively recently, you will need to look for contextual hints at what is really meant, or just live with the uncertainty.

The terms are probably often used interchangeably, but that is partly because it's not clear what "virtual filesystem" refers to. It is probably often used to refer to a filesystem that has no actual physical device providing storage (but I believe "pseudo filesystem" is a better term for that). It might also be used to refer to whatever is handled by the VFS (which stands for "Virtual File System" AFAIR) layer, underlying all filesystems.

The pseudo- prefix means "fake", while virtual means1 "not physically existing as such but made by software to appear to do so".
/proc is a pseudo-filesystem, because it's "files" are dynamically generated.
The "vfs" virtual filesystem is a kernel abstraction layer over physical (and in-memory) filesystems.  This hides implementation details, while presenting a common interface to userland programs (and probably other parts of the kernel).
Is there some overlap in nomenclature?  Sure, but natural language is messy like that.
1According to Google and https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en
